# How to use strong parameters on ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to ruby on rails 4, and I am trying to use strong parameters to require that a "project" exists before adding a "role" to a project.  The "role" itself requires a "project" to be associated to.

The issue that I am having is that with my current code, I am getting the error
`"undefined method`permit' for "1":String"` - how can I resolve this???

The error is identified in my "roles" controller -->

```
  private 
  def role_params
    params.require(:project_id).permit(:role)
  end

  def project
    @project ||= Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end`
```

My create method in the controller is

```
  def create
    @role = project.roles.create(role_params)
    new_was_successful = @role.save
  end
```

the model is:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  validates :project_id , :presence => true
end
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update

```
  def role_params
    params.require(:project_id).permit(:role)
  end
```

to

```
  def role_params
    params.require(:role).permit(:project_id) ## if more fields are present in role model then add them as arguments to permit  
  end
```

You are getting error because you have set the strong parameters incorrectly. In the params hash, you would get something like this:

Example :

```
"role"=>{"project_id"=>1,...} ### ... refers to other fields in role model, if present
```

**EDIT**

Update your `create` action as below

```
  def create
    @role = project.roles.create(role_params)
    if @role.save
      redirect_to @role, notice: 'Role was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end 
  end
```

Comment: Thanks!  Now the page renders, but when submitted it is not successful when all of the variables are provided in the form.  I guess thats my next task!

Comment: See my updated answer. If role was not created successfully then verify the params hash in the logs that all values from form are passed correctly or not. I think one of the validations would be failing in your model. You could check that too.